# mailto: HTML command don't work with Firefox portable and windows

Tags: html, windows, firefox, mailto

With **firefox portable** 36.0.1 (windows 7) this mailto: HTML command

```
<address>
Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>.<br>
Visit us at:<br>
Example.com<br>
Box 564, Disneyland<br>
USA
</address>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp

don't work. If I click on the link `Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>`, my email client start up, but email field remains empty. I remember with older firefox portable and Windows XP this work well.

Any hint what to do?

EDIT

use this fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rx78jws/1/)
my email programm start up, but to: field remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this fiddle on 36.0.4 which I got from [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).  It works fine on my computer in FireFox portable and on my other browsers.

It sounds like mailto: association is broken (or missing command line arguments) on your computer or mail program rather than on FireFox.  A quick test is to see if this works the same with other browsers on your system.

Try reconfiguring your mail program under the Default Programs control panel.  Choose "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program" and select the appropriate mail program.  If you have more than one, try a different one to see if it works.  There may be a way to do this from your mail client as well.

You didn't say what your mail program is.  I think I had a similar problem once with an old version of Windows Live Mail or GMail's shell integration.

Comment: That's sounds good. With IE 9.0 on the same PC every works well. My E-Mail client is "David" from Tobit. I will check your hint.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is, my E-Mail client "David" existst two times, only "...(Standard)" works complete and correct.

[image]

So hope for the best...